Understanding the flow of the kernel upon receiving a SIGSEGV for null-dereference
I'm trying to figure out the sequence of things that occur inside the Linux kernel (x86_64, v6.9) when we write these two codes:
// Null-dereference + writing to page zero
*(char *)0 = 0;

// Null-dereference + only reading from page zero
char c = *(char *)0;

I tried to analyze it with the Ftrace, and this is what I got:
handle_mm_fault <-- do_user_addr_fault
sanitize_fault_flags <-- handle_mm_fault
arch_vma_access_permitted <-- handle_mm_fault
bad_area_nosemaphore <-- do_user_addr_fault
__bad_area_nosemaphore <-- do_user_addr_fault
force_sig_fault <-- __bad_area_nosemaphore

So from my understanding, we cause a page fault, and somehow arch_vma_access_permitted() OR sanitize_fault_flags() decides to return VM_FAULT_SIGSEGV and __bad_area_nosemaphore() uses that to send a SIGSEGV to the process with force_sig_fault(). My question is, what is the permission of page zero? Does it even get mapped in the first place? If it doesn't, then I think vma_is_foreign() should cover this situation and cause the segmentation fault. I also found something interesting in load_elf_binary() for emulating the ABI behavior of previous Linux versions:
if (current->personality & MMAP_PAGE_ZERO) {
        /* Why this, you ask???  Well SVr4 maps page 0 as read-only,
           and some applications "depend" upon this behavior.
           Since we do not have the power to recompile these, we
           emulate the SVr4 behavior. Sigh. */
        error = vm_mmap(NULL, 0, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC,
                        MAP_FIXED | MAP_PRIVATE, 0);
}

The most confusing part of it is the PROT_EXEC. Why do we need to store instructions inside of page zero? And if it has PROT_READ as well, then while current->personality has MMAP_PAGE_ZERO, reading from page zero should not cause a segmentation fault, right? Couldn't find the SVr4 spec so I'm not sure about the details. I'm also not certain when this personality applies to a task but we can conclude that in some scenarios page zero GETS mapped (of course we can remap it by using mmap() if mmap_min_addr is zero, but I'm talking about the default behavior right now, not remapping). I can't find any other vm_mmap() or do_mmap() that is mapping page zero.


It might be mapped on some architectures. 2. On some architectures it might be a code that may be executed, like interrupt vectors. All in all, your question(s) are highly dependent on the exact hardware which you are not considering here.


@0andriy I specifically mentioned I'm asking about x86_64. I'm aware that even the functions that I mentioned are arch specific. AFAIK x86_64 (not all architectures ofc) should not allow the user to use page zero for security reasons, but things like vm86 needs the feature, that's why we can tune the mmap_min_addr. At least the remapping is not allowed by default.

Original i386 paging didn't allow you to turn off execute permissions per page; if a page was readable then it was automatically executable. So if emulating historical behavior, PROT_EXEC would make sense.

@NateEldredge Interesting, thanks for your answer. That solves one of the mysteries, but isn't this a security risk?

How? It all feels a bit dodgy, but any instruction that you can run from page 0, you also could have run from some other page. And you don't even get to choose the instructions, since the page is not writable.

@user555045 Uh you're right, I wasn't paying attention to the PROT_READ.

It can be a security issue if you're relying on the behavior that a null dereference should crash the program, and then it doesn't. On the other hand, if you're running binaries so old that they came from SysVr4, they're surely full of vulnerabilities already.

*(char *)0 = 0; is undefined behaviour in C because it derefs a null pointer.  You should at least make it (volatile char*) to encourage the compiler to actually do the access instead of e.g. emitting an instruction like ud2 (illegal instruction #UD trap -> SIGILL) or other surprising things like optimizing away all the instructions from a function like clang does: https://godbolt.org/z/EWYGGqY5M   Modern C is not a portable assembly language.  Either write in asm or do more to hide your shenanigans from being visible at compile-time, like store the pointer in char *volatile tmp

Security risk as in not hardening against Spectre and ROP attacks by potentially having bytes in an executable page that didn't need to be there, so can be used as gadgets.  But like @NateEldredge says, SysVr4 binaries at worst have full-on vulnerabilities, and at best are already not hardened at all, e.g. non-PIE so no ASLR for .text/.data/.bss, and all those pages will be executable since they probably also get the READ_IMPLIES_EXEC personality bit.  So probably no W^X either.

A page mapped at virt address zero could allow execution to get past a null-deref with bogus data instead of crashing, making some bugs into security vulnerabilities, so yeah you might want to objcopy an executable into a more modern Linux ELF executable or whatever other way might exist to have it run without this personality if it doesn't rely on it, and you can't just recompile it from source.

@PeterCordes I'm not sure how volatile helps. Could replace the integer constant 0 with a compound literal 0 viz. *(char *)(int){0} = 0;.

@IanAbbott: Right, it's still a null deref, but it's a volatile access so some compilers might be more faithful in making it happen in the asm.  Like clang makes the asm we wanted, but GCC uses ud2 instead of ret afterwards.  Your idea also doesn't avoid that for GCC (and for clang only with volatile char*).  We can use char *volatile p = 0; return *p; to defeat constant propagation, hiding the UB from the optimizer, to make actual working asm.  https://godbolt.org/z/eeh44E5ee


what is the permission of page zero? Does it even get mapped in the first place?

It doesn't. Except the quirky piece of code you show, or other exceptions like userspace explicitly requesting to map it when vm.mmap_min_addr = 0, no page is usually ever mapped at virtual address zero. Even if it was, the behavior would be the same as any other page, the fact that the virtual address is zero doesn't really make it special.
When the fault occurs for the program you show, it will end up exactly inside this branch of do_user_addr_fault(), because the process does not have a mapping (vma) for 0x0:
    ...
lock_mmap:

retry:
    vma = lock_mm_and_find_vma(mm, address, regs);
    if (unlikely(!vma)) {
        bad_area_nosemaphore(regs, error_code, address); // <== HERE
        return;
    }
    ...

Not sure why you are mentioning vma_is_foreign(), but that cannot really be called if you don't have a vma to begin with. bad_area_nosemaphore() will be the one responsible for SIGSEGV delivery, calling force_sig_fault(), which then calls another series of functions to deliver the signal.


The most confusing part of it is the PROT_EXEC. Why do we need to store instructions inside of page zero?

Old software expects that read-implies-exec behavior because that's just how the hardware used to work. In fact, this is still the case for older x86 32-bit CPUs and even for some 32-bit software running on x86_64. Take a look at this comment for example.

And if it has PROT_READ as well, then while current->personality has MMAP_PAGE_ZERO, reading from page zero should not cause a segmentation fault, right?

Right.

I'm also not certain when this personality applies to a task

It mainly depends on the underlying architecture. Arch-specific code chooses which personality bits to toggle on new execs. The SET_PERSONALITY and SET_PERSONALITY2 macros are defined by each arch and you can see the different definitions here and here.
